# IE8 Submits the form but sometimes doesn't refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, submit

I have a button and when I click that button a function works, it calls jQuery .submit function.

I use jQuery 1.4.2.

However, sometimes it submits but doesn't refresh the page. I got this problem just on IE8.

Actually it works on IE8 but sometimes I get this problem and sometimes not.

My page is like that; there are some text fields and a chechboxes near every text field. I check the checkbox and push the delete button, it submits the value and that  text field disappear(it is deleted at server side and the page reloads all the text fields that saved at server side). The problem is that sometimes that textfield doesn't disappear from the screen but if I re-enter page's url and push enter or F5 the page or check the checkbox and push the delete button again everything works fine...

Comment: Post some code.. it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was about my server side structure, was not related to only ie8.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like browser caching issue. To solve this, when you submit the form add random value to its `action`, thus tricking the browser to think it's different page so it won't load the contents from its cache.

Sample code:

```
var rand = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000 + 100000);
$(form).attr("action", "mypage.php?r=" + rand);
...
```

Comment: I got the problem. Thanks for your help but i realized that my problem is about database synchronization between master and slave database so i gonna fix it related to that problem.

Comment: @kamaci OK, though can't see why it happened only for IE8.

Comment: Actually your solution is nice but i think that submitting is not using cache and refreshes the page. I could eventually got that this problem at firefox too but i still think that there maybe something wrong wit ie8.